# Invoking `constexpr` member function through reference - clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++20

Consider the following example (**snippet (0)**):

```
struct X
{
    constexpr int get() const { return 0; }
};

void foo(const X& x)
{
    constexpr int i = x.get();
}

int main()
{
    foo(X{});
}
```

The above example compiles with all versions of `g++` prior to `g++ 10.x`, and never compiled under `clang++`. The error message is:

> ```
> error: 'x' is not a constant expression
>     8 |     constexpr int i = x.get();
>       |
> ```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qvTQFc)

The error kind of makes sense, as `x` is never a constant expression in the body of `foo`, however:

- `X::get()` is marked `constexpr` and it does not depend on the state of `x`;
- Changing `const X&` to `const X` makes the code compile with every compiler [*(on godbolt.org)*](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/p_8KSd) **snippet (1)**.

---

It gets even more interesting when I mark `X::get()` as `static` ([*(on godbolt.org)*](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2B55AM) **snippet (2)**). With that change, all tested versions of `g++` (including trunk) compile, while `clang++` still always fail to compile.

So, my questions:

- Is `g++ 9.x` correct in accepting **snippet (0)**?
- Are all compilers correct in accepting **snippet (1)**? If so, why is the reference significant?
- Are `g++ 9.x` and `g++ trunk` correct in accepting **snippet (2)**?

Comment: constexpr is a 'mask' to a value and a const is a variable that you inform it won't be changed. Values can't be referenced or pointed but const does. The get() function member is processed in compile time. In other words it is 0 to all cases. As I said before, values can't be referenced or pointed

Comment: I think [\[expr.const\]/2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11) applies here, and `x` in `foo` is not a constant expression. There's even [an old (informally rejected) bug report on clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25693) for its correct behaviour (whereas GCC had an actual bug for it).

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [Invalid explicitly-specified argument in clang but successful compilation in gcc — who's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872039) or [Why is a constexpr function on a reference not constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124899).

Comment: Wrote about this recently, seems relevant: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/

Comment: @Barry nice, in your article you also have the reference to the corresponding [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66477) (I could onloy find the the rejected clang one) which allowed gcc 9.x to accept snippet 0, which has since corrected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

| Deprecation Notice |
| --- |
| This answer is now obsolete due to the changes in [P2280: Using unknown pointers and references in constant expressions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html) (proposal accepted into C++23 and applied as a defect report to C++11). **GCC 9** falsely accepts the code as a bug. **GCC 10-13** reject the code due to a bug fix, but do not implement P2280 yet. **GCC 14** implements the DR and accepts the original code as valid. See https://godbolt.org/z/KE5G969ca. |

> Is g++ 9.x correct in accepting snippet (0)?

No.

> Are all compilers correct in accepting snippet (1)? If so, why is the reference significant?

Yes, they are.

A constant expression cannot use an id-expression naming a reference that doesn't have a previous constant expression initialization or began its lifetime during the constant expression evaluation. [[expr.const]/2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11) ([same in C++20](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.12))

The same is not true if you are naming a non-reference variable without involving any lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. `x.get()` only refers to `x` as lvalue and only calls a `constexpr` function that doesn't actually access any member of `x`, so there is no issue.

> Are g++ 9.x and g++ trunk correct in accepting snippet (2)?

No, because the expression still contains the subexpression `x` which violates the rule mentioned above.

Comment: [Relevant (informally rejected) bug report on clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25693) pointing out the same correctness in clang (always) failing to compile snippet 0.